# How to generate 6-Rooks jitter pattern for anti-aliasing text rendering?

Tags: opengl, antialiasing, text-rendering

I am reading a project which use 6-Rooks jitter pattern to make anti-aliasing SVG text rendering, and the jitter pattern is as below:

```
var JITTER_PATTERN = [
    Vector.new(-1 / 12.0, -5 / 12.0),
    Vector.new( 1 / 12.0,  1 / 12.0),
    Vector.new( 3 / 12.0, -1 / 12.0),
    Vector.new( 5 / 12.0,  5 / 12.0),
    Vector.new( 7 / 12.0, -3 / 12.0),
    Vector.new( 9 / 12.0,  3 / 12.0),
]
```

and I don't know how these values are generated, and the layout of this 6-rooks is as below:

[image: 6 samples layout for 6 rooks jitter patter]

I just know these set of values are just one set of the possible values, and can anyone tell me how to generate these values?